# Pandas: calculating ratio between values of dataset for some subset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which looks like

| value |
| --- |
| 34 |
| 45 |
| 3 |
| -3 |

I want to calculate ratio of values for this dataset, i.e. ratio of value to next value:
34/45 , 45/3, 3/-3

I can do it via `myDataset["value"]/myDataset["value"].shift(-1)`

Next step is more complex and that is where I an struggling. I need to calculate same ratio, but for selected set of values. The criteria of selection is that value should be greater than previous one. I.e. this time resulting dataset should contains 45/3 only.
I started with

```
myDataset.loc[(myDataset["value"] > myDataset["value"].shift(1)),"value] /  myDataset.loc[(myDataset["value"] > myDataset["value"].shift(1)),"value].shift(-1)
```

But its not what I want because myDataset.loc changes the dataset itself, so next value found by this is not really next, but next which fits condition in (). While I need really next value from original dataset.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**

> It looks like my description was a bit misleading. If I have a list of
> a,b,c,d then I want to return
>
> c/b if b>a
>
> d/c if c>b
>
> I dont want to return c/b if c>b, its pretty straightforward.

Comment: By the way, `3 > -3`, so there should be two returned values no?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new shifted column, and work with that:

```
df['shifted'] = df.value.shift(-1)

print(df.value/df.shifted)
print()
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.value/x.shifted if x.value > x.shifted else None, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0     0.755556
1    15.000000
2    -1.000000
3          NaN
dtype: float64

0     NaN
1    15.0
2    -1.0
3     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Looks like same issue as with other replies:
If list is a,b,c then I want to return c/b only if b > a. While your example - if I read correct - returns a/b if b>a, c/b if c>b etc
But its easy to fix : we just need to have 2 shifted columns: shiftedForward (shift(1)), shiftedBackward (shift(-11)), and if value>shiftedForward then apply shiftedBackward value, right?

Comment: Updated the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```py
value = df.value
diff = value.diff()
div = value.shift(-1) / value
div[value.diff() > 1]
```

### Output

```
1    0.066667
```

### Explain

1. `diff()` equivalent to `value - value.shift()`
2. `div` keep the ratio `c/b`

Comment: Well, its not quite what I need. 
If list is a,b,c then I want to return c/b only if b > a. While your example - if I read correct - returns a/b if b>a, c/b if c>b etc

Comment: Updated the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Following the updated question, you can zip three items instead of two.

You can do this with a list comprehension (this will return only ratios that meet the condition):

```
[b/c for a, b, c in zip(df["value"].shift(2), df["value"].shift(1), df["value"]) if a>b]
#Out:
#[-1.0]
```

The only valid option is 43/3, so the only ratio is 3/-3=-1

Comment: Looks good! But the ratio I need to return is not the same as ratio which is a selection condition.
I.e. if list is a,b,c then I want to return c/b only if b > a.
While your example - if I read correct - returns a/b if b>a, c/b if c>b etc

Comment: Updated the ticket.

Comment: I have updated my answer, hopefully that solves your question.